# Django + Vue.js issue

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

I want to implement Vue.js at my Django project.

```
Code: 

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="demo">
        <p>{{message}}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var demo = new Vue({
            el: '#demo',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Works everywhere except my django project. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the braces with the tag [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) in your template:

```
<div id="demo">
    <p>{% verbatim %}{{message}}{% endverbatim %}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is Vue.js template syntax clash with Django template syntax (as for Jinja2). Both techno uses `{{` and `}}`.

But Vue.js can be easily configured to use another opening and closing characters for variable replacement:

```
<body>
    <div id="demo">
        <p>${message}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var demo = new Vue({
            delimiters: ['${', '}'],
            el: '#demo',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

See [Vue.js delimiters API doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters).

Comment: had this same problem with angular. ended up swapping the curly delimiters with square brackets...